# o365 security and compliance reports

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, reports

I am using the security and compliance reports to investigate the deletion of some files

I have set to search in a particular site collection for the files deleted and set a timeframe of 3 months (3 months before now). I get no results. Is the time span reliable? Is there an untold limit for which if the dates are too far apart the system will not show results?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation I have experienced. Only thing is you cant search for date range which you have not activated audit logging. other than that you can only maximum of 50,000 entries to a CSV file from a single audit log search and download.